# PHP Report - 1 Master line and multiple details listed

Tags: php, mysql, report

I'm a newbie so please excuse me if I use the wrong terminology, still learning.

I'm working with PHP & MYSQL.  Trying to create a report that will display as such:

```
  Customer Name: Bill 
    Doctor:  Dr. A 
    Diagnosis: diagnosis #1
               diagnosis #2
               diagnosis #3

    Signature:_________________________

    <hr> <new page> 
    Customer Name: Steve
    Doctor:  Dr. B
    Diagnosis: diagnosis #1
               diagnosis #2

    Signature:__________________________ 
    <hr> <new page> 
    <next record>
```

Their are 2 tables involved, Customer_info and Diagnosis  and they are setup in a one-to-many relationship.  Essentially each customer can have multiple diagnosis.

Here is the code I have so far:

I'm close except for the SIGNATURE LINE and the PAGE BREAK.  I don't know what code needs to used or where in order to get it at the end of each record.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result)
{
$currGroup = -1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   if($row['hap_customer_id'] != $currGroup)
    {
        echo '<hr>';
        $currGroup = $row['hap_customer_id'];
        echo '</h4>';   
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<b>Customer Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' .  $row['customer_name'] . "<br>";
        echo '<b>Doctor: &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' . $row['doctor'] . "<br>";
        echo '<br>';    
    }
    echo '<b>A/P: &nbsp;&nbsp;</b>' . $row['diagnosis'] . "</br>";
   }    
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: well, first of all i want to clear the problem.. what you ask is practically a `html` related stuff instead of php. as for page break, you can define it using css as [this article explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030581/php-report-1-master-line-and-multiple-details-listed#) - ps you could create a custom html tag anyway, so instead of footer like on the example, you could use _pagebreak_ and page breaks will occur after `<pagebreak>` tag. regarding your issue with signature line, you could cheat with underline and white space (`&nbsp;`) right?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've determined what code to use in order to get the signature line and the pagebreak.  The issue is where to put it.  If it goes below the last echo statement, then each diagnosis line has a signature line.  If I put it lower in the code, then I get 1 signature line but only on the last record.  I don't get one for each record.  So with that, I believe this is a php related issue.

Comment: ok, to summarize, you wish to show every customer with each of it's diagnosis. with each customer shown you have to put signature field? well, didn't you fetch each customer, then for each customer fetch their respective diagnosis - thus you'll have two iteration, one for iterating customer, one for iterating diagnosis. [just an idea..](https://anotepad.com/notes/9rbfxc)